# how to console log the return value from promise Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize and I am not able to log the value of a promise. I'm doing `console.log('helooo',  timekeep);` but it prints `Promise { <pending> }`. I don't know if I am doing it right or not.

This is my code:

```
const create = async function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let err, orders, wallet;
    let orders_info = req.body;  
    console.log('order_info : <<<<<< ' + JSON.stringify(orders_info));
    var timekeep =  Orders.findAndCountAll(
    {
        where: {
          cid : orders_info.cid,
        },      
        order: [
          ['id', 'DESC']
        ],
        limit: 1,
      }
   )
   .then(result => {
       console.log('hello', result);
       console.log(result.count);
       console.log(result.rows);
   });
   console.log('helooo',  timekeep);
}
```

I am getting like this when I log the var.

```
helooo
Promise {
_bitField: 0,
_fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
_rejectionHandler0: undefined,
_promise0: undefined,
_receiver0: undefined }
```

Answer (score 0):

`timekeep` is the value you return from `then` clause, which is `Promise<void>`, because no value is returned from it.

The `result` which you print with `console.log('hello', result);` has the value you wanted from the Promise.

Comment: yes, but I am not able to use 'result' outside  function

Comment: right, because it's defined only inside the `then`. if you return the `result` and add `await` before `Orders.findAndCountAll` you will have the value at `timekeep`

Answer (score 0):

I can see your `create` function is already an `async` function. So, instead of using Promise syntax, use async/await syntax. Now what you are trying to do is to assign the query expression to variable `timekeep`. Here is the sample code,

```
const create = async function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let err, orders, wallet;
    let orders_info = req.body;
    console.log('order_info : <<<<<< ' + JSON.stringify(orders_info));
    // try resolving promise
    try {
        var timekeep = await Orders.findAndCountAll(
            {
                where: {
                    cid: orders_info.cid,
                },
                order: [
                    ['id', 'DESC']
                ],
                limit: 1,
            }
        );
        console.log("RESULT => ", timekeep)
    } catch (err) {
        // catch error here
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are minor issues with returning data and `async await` concept , please review below code with comment :

```
var timekeep = await Orders.findAndCountAll({ // <----------- you need add await
    where: {
        cid: orders_info.cid,
    },
    order: [
        ['id', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit: 1,
})
.then(result => {
    console.log('hello', result);
    console.log(result.count);
    console.log(result.rows);
    return result; // <----------- also need to return the result from here
});
console.log('helooo', timekeep); // <----- Now check the console
```